# I am looking forward to ....? (followed by a Gerund)?

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech, construction

I know, that

> I am looking forward to hearing from you.

is correct.
But I am not sure, if this holds also for other verbs?

So is

> I am looking forward to taste your cookies.

or is

> I am looking forward to tasting your cookies.

correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed. In each case, you need an object, so you need a noun or noun phrase:

> I am looking forward to the holidays.

So in order to make a verb serve you must use the gerund.

> I am looking forward to taking some time off.

Comment: All complement clauses (_that_-clauses, _wh_-clauses, infinitive causes, and gerund clauses) are noun phrases. It happens that _look forward to_ requires a gerund clause and does not allow any of the others. Every predicate has its own individual settings.