# To + -ING form: e.g. "to getting"?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

> I look forward ***to getting*** first-hand insights and behind-the-scene perspectives from XXX’s professors  who are thought leaders and experts in their fields.

Should I replace *to getting* with *to get* ?

I checked on other forums regarding to + -ING vs infinitive form, but I didn't find a satisfactory answer.

The *to getting* doesn't seem correct while speaking.

Comment: related: [How to use “to + V-ing”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/how-to-use-to-v-ing/38967#38967); [Why was _to_ verb_+ing_ used in this case?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57230/why-was-to-verb-ing-used-in-this-case?lq=1) and [I am looking forward to …? (followed by a Gerund)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127554/i-am-looking-forward-to-followed-by-a-gerund)

Comment: @Mari-LouA +1 yes! This is a great example of K.I.S.S. (keep it simple stupid)  Sometimes the easiest solution is right under our nose.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the verbs like **afraid of, speak about**, etc. The -ing form is required after such verbs with prepositions. **Look forward to** is one of those verbs where **to** is the preposition, not a part of infinitive. For instance,

*We spoke about going on a trip at the weekend.
I'm afraid of staying alone at home.
I'm looking forward to getting e-mail from my penpal.*

Now consider these examples with infinitive.

*I decided to pursue my education abroad.
Tom wanted to help me.*

We cannot say that to in these sentences is preposition used after the verbs, instead it's part of the infinitives.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need the -ing, but it does sound a little awkward to me. I would simply replace *getting* with *learning*.

Answer (score 0):

***Getting*** is more correct here, but this kind of construction should be accompanied by a time (specific, like 8 am, or general, like *soon* or *at the party*). The tense is [future progressive/continuous tense](http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/future_continuous), which is generally used to indicate that we will be in the middle of an action at a specified time, or making a guess about the future. Some similar constructions:

- I look forward to **eating** dinner with you tomorrow.
- I look forward to **meeting** people at the party.
- I look forward to **hearing** from you soon.

It's important to note that the verb here is not infinitive: it's not **to getting** or **to eating**, but "I [look forward to] **getting**".

Future progressive is more commonly used with the word **will**, like "I will be swimming all afternoon", which makes it more clear what part of the sentence the **to** is part of. If you replaced the phrase "look forward to" with "will be" in your sentence, you get the following:

> I *will be* getting first-hand insights and behind-the-scene
>   perspectives from XXX’s professors who are thought leaders and experts
>   in their fields.

I don't know if it's grammatical without the time, though, so perhaps the following would be better:

> I look forward to getting first-hand insights and behind-the-scene
>   perspectives from XXX’s professors who are thought leaders and experts
>   in their fields *tomorrow*.

Or *at the conference*, *soon*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In standard NZ English,,, and everywhere else that I can remember where the user is a native English speaker, "look/ing/ed forward to,," Always has the --ing ending on a verb.

eg She looks forward to havING Marmite on her toast.

I looked forward to gettING mail from China.

The tense of the action has no effect on the format.